# Morewrites blank lists

Tags: morewrites

I’ve just tried adding the `morewrites` package to get around a “too many writes” error when using the `\listof` command from the `floats` package.

The document compiles, but the lists are all empty. I’ve pulled down the most recent MacTeX install, which did not resolve the problem.

What should I be looking at next to track down and resolve the problem?

Edit: I've just tracked down a key part of the problem: If any of `afterpage`, `noindentafter`, or `tabto` are loaded after `morewrites`, the table of contents and list of figures are empty, e.g.,

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{morewrites}
\usepackage{noindentafter}

\begin{document}

\title{Morewrite doesn't play with noindentafter}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\vspace{2ex}
\hrule
\section{First Section}
Text for the first section.
\section{Second Section}
Text for the second section.

\end{document}
```

(loading the other packages before morewrites makes things work as expected).

--

Second edit: My first MWE seems to have been incorrect. Reworking my way through the packages in my document leads me to a MWE of

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage{morewrites}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{stackengine}



\begin{document}

\title{Morewrite doesn't play with stackengine}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\vspace{2ex}
\hrule
\section{First Section}
Text for the first section.
\section{Second Section}
Text for the second section.

\end{document}
```

which produces a two-page document with a title on the first page, and page number "2" on the second page. If I comment out either of `afterpage` or `stackengine`, place `afterpage` after `stackengine`, or `morewrites` after the other two packages, I get a 3-page document with a table of contents and the text of the document.

Comment: can you post a small complete example that demonstrates the problem?  One thing to check is has the text that should have been written gone _somewhere_ (eg the main toc, or the log file or ....) also check for spaces in filenames

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not sure in this case how to whittle my set of files down to an MWE. Looking at the directory, it seems like the contents of the .toc and .lof files are getting sent to a .wrt file instead of where they should go. Does that suggest anything I should look for?

Comment: that just means its working as designed (in parts) morewrites gets round the restriction of having at most 16 files open by writing to a single wrt file so you only need one write channel open and then sorting them out at the end. Oh that does mean that you need to get to the end, if you quit at (any) error the writes won't happen.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I believe the document is compiling without any errors (latexmk completes its multiple-pass algorithm, I get the warning+count for unresolved references and duplicate labels, and the compiled pdf appears). Should I expect to be seeing the .wrt file appear in the log or console output? (I'm not seeing it referenced in either location)

Comment: Don't use latexmk to debug such a problem. Run pdflatex and so on individually.

Comment: I tried with the three mentioned packages and find no problem. By the way, `noindentafter` has not been updated for the new LaTeX kernel and doesn't work. Not a big issue, because I find it really useless.

Comment: Apologies -- There seems to be some aspect of my document or environment state that I'm missing in my debugging process. I can toggle the appearance or disappearance of the contents lists in my full document by the relative order of the usepackage calls, but it's working intermittently on the MWEs I'm constructing. I will dig deeper.

Comment: As a global comment (and perhaps unhelpful) I will say that I struggled so much with morewrites causing many obscure problems. I eventually gave up, reduced my write streams and have been a happier and more wholesome person since then. It causes havoc. I also ended up with literally thousands of redundant files written to by morewrites which were never cleaned up properly before the next run. I gave up trying to debug it. That said, afterpage - also in your list - is the second most problematical package I have encountered.

Comment: I can reproduce the findings from your MWE (2 pages vs 3 pages). Compiling on Win 10, TexLive, compiling as latexmk -xelatex --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode